# Expanding a UIObject with Native Class of TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, hp-uft, leanft

**Original Question**

I have this expandable folder UIObject that I need to be able to expand to show all the subfolders. It can not be double clicked as this does not expand the folders. I saw from this documentation, https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.02/NetSDKReference/HP.LFT.SDK~HP.LFT.SDK.Java.ITreeView.html as well as some others that there is a concept of an ITreeView and an ITreeViewNode.

How can I expand this element? I really just need some examples in code of how we can take an object, defeine it as a ITreeView and ITreeView node and expand it.

**Result**

Even though it is not the best solution, it is possible to do this using the Workaround suggested below and this is the method that made it happen

```
public void ExpandFolder(int index)
{
        IUiObject folder = ViewPage.FolderExplorer.Describe<IUiObject>(new UiObjectDescription
        {
            ObjectName = "TreeViewItem",
            Index = (uint)index
        });

        var expandButton = folder.AbsoluteLocation;
        expandButton.X = expandButton.X + 2;
        expandButton.Y = expandButton.Y + 4;

        Mouse.Click(expandButton);

        GeneralUtilities.Sleep(1);
}
```

In this case, there was a small drop down arrow to the left of the element. I couldn't identify that, so I identified the folder and manipulated the click. If anyone stumbles upon this and knows a more direct way to do this using LeanFT I would very much like to see an example. If not, and you are here trying to find help - I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The theory

In order to `Expand` and `Collapse` a Java `ITreeView`, these are the steps:

1. Describe the `ITreeView`:

   ```
   ITreeView treeView = Desktop.Describe<IWindow>(new WindowDescription())
       .Describe<ITreeView>(new TreeViewDescription()
       {
           AttachedText = "Etc"
       });
   ```
2. Get one of it's nodes:

   ```
   ITreeViewNode treeViewNode = treeView.GetNode("someNode");
   ```
3. Expand or collapse it:

   ```
   treeViewNode.Expand(); treeViewNode.Collapse();
   ```

The only expandable object is the `ITreeViewNode` (that is, this is the one that has the `.Expand` method), and the only way to get to the node is via an `ITreeView`, as shown above.

### In practice...

You want to take an `UIObject` *(I suspect this is what object identification center identified, right?)* **as an `ITreeView`**, so that you can call `Expand` and `Collapse` on it?

This is not possible.

1. In these SDKs, every description is a generic element. In Java it's a `UIObject`, in Web it's a `WebElement`, etc..
2. Those more unique, like a tree view, extend the generic one (`UIObject`) and adds one more identification property in the process
3. In the `ITreeView` case, most probably it's the `UIObject` **with** `NativeClass` set as `"javax.swing.JTree"`

If Object Identification Center didn't identify the expandable object as an `ITreeView`, it's because it isn't.

### Workaround

If your goal is just to expand, and manually double clicking works, then you can:

1. Identify the `UIObject`;
2. Calculate the coordinates of the point you manually double click, relative to the upper left pixel of the `UIObject`. (E.G. 5 pixels down, 5 to the right)

   You can approximate it, go for a try and error, or use tools that can help.
3. Use `HP.LFT.SDK.Mouse` class to double click that exact location:

   ```
   var loc = theUiButton.AbsoluteLocation;
   var p = new System.Drawing.Point(loc.X + 5, loc.Y + 5);

   Mouse.DoubleClick(p, MouseButton.Left);
   ```

   The reason why it doesn't work right now is because `.DoubleClick`, by default, performs double click in the center of the `UIObject`, and I have a hunch that's not where the expandable object is - so you need to provide fine tuning parameters.